# Handling private information

Tags: discussion

Another of my newest concerns is handling private user information when accidentally pasted into the code part of a question or answer.

Can we proactively edit that? I tried but it requires "peer review" so it's in a holding pattern and this poor guy's darned ROOT password is hanging out there in the breeze.

Answer (score 4):

If you run into this type of situation (anything that cannot be handled by the normal user processes), **you should immediately 'flag' the post for Moderator attention.**

That is why Moderators♦ are called "exception handlers"… for precisely this type of situation. Not only can Moderators edit out the information immediately, they can also let us know we need to remove the revision history that would show the remnants of the original post.

Comment: Aha, and that's why I asked.  I'm new to SE/SO and I didn't know the difference.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Even if you edit it the password will be in the revision history and likely caught in things like google cache. In such an event the only type of action would be for the user to change his root password. There is not much more we can do to fix what should be common sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2000 reputation points to edit a post without peer review, I accepted your change. But I think it is still in the history.

Answer (score -2):

I think we should edit it as much as we can.

Comment: Dmitry, just FYI; the down-votes are likely because your answer doesn't really address the question being asked.